# Convert negative decimal number to positive in java spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I have the below dataframe.

```
column_1
2.1
-3.4
-1.1
2.5
```

I want to convert this column to positive numbered column when the value is less than 0 or in other words if its negative value. Input is in decimal format and output should also be in decimal format.

I tried converting to string and using abs(column_1) when lt(0) and then cast it as decimal. But all values are getting converted to null.

Any idea how to achieve this in Java spark.

Required output:

```
column_1
2.1
3.4
1.1
2.5
```

Comment: This should work: `df.select(abs('column_1').alias('column_1')).show()` (with `abs` being imported from spark sql's functions)

Comment: Will the output of abs() still be in decimal format ? Or will it get converted to float ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `abs`, which is available in Pyspark via the functions package [[Docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.abs) but also can be used via the SQL API [[Docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#abs).

Pyspark

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('column_1', F.abs('column_1')
```

Spark SQL

```sql
SELECT abs(column_1)
FROM df;
```